# Check if the sum of two elements with same id of two elemeents is negative

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two 2d-arrays:

## example

```
ar1 = [['2001-01-01', 100], ['2001-01-02', 105],...]

ar2 = [['2001-01-01', 100], ['2001-01-02', 120],...]
```

## problem

I need to know, if any of the [i][1] elements of the arrays subtracted from each other result in a negative number. What kind of loop should I go with to get the best performance and the smartest code?

Comment: the answer should be boolean for each array? The result is true if any pair has a negative difference? In that case, the only way it could be false would be for every number to be equal to each other.

Comment: As I understand you, the difference needs to be calculated by something like `parseInt(ar1[i][1]) - parseInt(ar2[i][1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop is the simplest

```
for (i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++) {
  if (ar1[i][1] < ar2[i][1]) {
    console.log(ar1[i][0]);
  }
}
```